# Compare object name (reference name) with a string

Tags: java

How to compare name of an object to a string in Java?

For example:

```
class_name obj = new class_name();
```

and I want to compare object name `obj` with a string. What is the correct way to do that?

Comment: That is completely impossible.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Please don't use underscores in classnames. Java Naming Convention: `Class names should be nouns, in mixed case with the first letter of each word capitalized.` Adhering to this keeps other developers from cringing when reading your code.

Comment: @Ask_it did you checked my answer..??

Answer (score 8):

That can't be done directly in Java. Variable *names* are merely a convenience for the programmer and are not even kept track of after your code is compiled. You can instead use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) that maps string identifiers to their corresponding objects. Or you can add a `name` field to your class which holds a string (`"obj"` in your example):

```
ClassName obj = new ClassName("obj");

if (obj.getName().equals(...))
    ...
```

(Note that I've assumed a more standard naming convention.)

Answer (score 0):

`==` compares object references. It finds out if the two operands point to the same object.

If you want to check if two strings contain same characters, you need to compare the strings using `equals`.

As to your concrete problem, it can't be done.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the class' class name by invoking `obj.getClass()`. You can't get the variable name of an object through normal means.

Comment: or through any other means, as the information is not present in bytecode.

Answer (score 0):

**You can check the Type of the Object Using `instanceof` keyword**

Look this examples for more details

```
public void checkType(Object param) {
  if( param instanceof String) {
    System.out.println("param is a String");
  }
  else if( param instanceof Integer) {
    System.out.println("param is an Integer");
  }
}
```

**I believe this is the right way to do it..!!**

You can look [***here***](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E15919_01/wlp.1032/e14255/com/bea/p13n/expression/operator/Instanceof.html) for more details

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access Local variables and if Source code is compiled with `javac -g` option to retain debug info, [Bytecode Library like ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) can be used to retrieve this details. See  [4.3. Debug](http://download.forge.objectweb.org/asm/asm4-guide.pdf)

> Classes compiled with javac -g contain the name of their source file,
>   a map- ping between source line numbers and bytecode instructions, and
>   a mapping betwen local variable names in source code and local
>   variable slots in bytecode. This optional information is used in
>   debuggers and in exception stack traces when it is available

If you want to retrieve name of class level /Field variables you could use [java reflection API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).